# With multiple processes, can one process (p1) send a SIGALRM timing signal that is received by two or more processes (p1, p2).?

Tags: signals, tcsh, processes, process-groups

I think I now know the answer. Since the processes p2, p3, ...., are all children of the same parent p1, then all the processes are in the same process group so any signal (e.g. SIGALRM ??) set by p1 will be received by each of p2, p3, ...
Is that correct?  I'll try it out.
-- Peter R

Answer (score 2):

I can't say for a `tcsh` builtin named `kill`, if any, but the `kill` system call, and the `/bin/kill` command that uses it, both offer to send a signal to all the processes belonging to the same process group PGRP, by specifying -PGRP as the target PID.

For example:

```
/bin/kill -- -PGRP
/bin/kill -SIG -PGRP
```

Else, by default, your signal is sent to the process specified by PID, and only this one.